# Getting a specific column in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I know this is a common problem that has many stackoverflow posts, but I still can't seem to fix my problem. I am trying to print a specific column in a CSV file using the following code:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

This seems to be the syntax I see on most online posts, but for some reason it does not work for me - I am getting an "index out of bounds" error each time I run it. I am not sure what that means in this context - my csv has several non-empty columns for each row. If I write

```
print row
```

I get an output. Furthermore, I verified that the type of that output is a list. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

The problem seems to have been resolved...and I'm not sure why as the code seems to be the same:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

I'm sorry I don't have a definitive answer to this for others that might stumble upon this. But thanks to those who tried to help!

Comment: Unless there is literally no data, a 0-index should *something*. What does your data look like? Which row of the is printed before it causes the error?

Comment: Hi Lego Stormtroopr, there is no output before it gives me the error. The file contains a mix of strings and dates. The first column is full of strings.

Comment: So it gives an error on the very first line?

Comment: Are you sure about your delimiter and record terminator?

Comment: Yes, I would paste the error here, but I am running it in Powershell and don't really know how to copy from there, but if I press run it immediately gives me an error

Comment: Also your formatting is off, under the with block should be indented.

Comment: Oops you are right, that was a copy-error - I'll fix it now. However, that is not the source of the error.

Comment: What about your delimiter?  Is it a comma?  And your record terminator is a \n?

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted - please let me know. Again, I know that this is a widely-documented segment of code but as Lego Stormtroopr pointed out this is an unusual problem right?

Comment: Your formatting is still wrong. :p Sorry.  print row[0] should be indented.

Comment: Woot - thanks for the help. I'm actually not sure what the record terminator is. There are commas when I type "print row" within each list. There are no \n at the ends - there are printed back to back. Please let me know if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Does your file have any purely empty records?  That's the only thing I can think of that might cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file for blank lines, that could cause the row to have empty lists.  Try to find the offending rows with:

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    counter = 0
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 0:
            counter += 1
            print counter, row
```

Comment: There are no blank lines - I have double checked this.

Comment: Try if len(row) == 0: print row to find the offending row?

Comment: I get four empty lists.

Comment: ok. Now add an counter to find the line number.  counter = 0, then counter += 1 in the for loop and print it with the row.

Comment: Hmm...I get [] []1 []4 []5 (printed vertically) - they have data in the csv, and seem no different from the other rows.

Comment: It's possible that your End of line markers are not as expected.  Possibly view them under a hex editor or readline() and hexify it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help woot. This seems to be beyond my level - can I do this within Python with readline() or do I need to get another program?

Comment: You can look [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HexDumpInManyProgrammingLanguages) for a quick dump to hex program.  Search for the Python one.

Comment: Hey woot thanks for your help, for some reason the code decided to work. I think literally nothing in the code changed and I didn't hexify anything. But I'll give you the answer for helping with this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ghost in the machine.